# Cloth simulation dirty in render

Tags: rendering, shadows

I want to take a render picture of the cloth over a car. But every time I render it the cloth shadows are too big and somehow not nice (whole cloth with shadows are just 3 colours).
[image: big shadows all over the cloth]

It looks good in the not-rendered form. But I cant figure out how to make the cloth-shades nice in the render-version.
[image]
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What material are you using in the cloth object? looks like a toon shader

Comment: I am using Glossy BSDF for the cloth

Comment: That is not the proper shader to get the look of a piece of fabric, either try a *Velvet* shader or mix the *Glossy* shader with a *Diffuse* one

Comment: Yes it looks much nicer as velvet. Thank you!